# Aligning elements with vertical-align: bottom doesn't work

Tags: html, css, alignment

I know it is an humiliating and basic problem, but I can't align the navigation div (green borders) with the logo div (red borders) in the bottom of the parent div (blue borders). I tried vertical-align: bottom, but didn't work, any suggestions?

[image]

HTML:

```
<div id="banner">
        <h1><a href="http://widerdesign.co.nr/">wider design</a></h1>
        <ul id="lang">
            <li><a href="index.php">English</a></li>
            <li><a href="es/index.php">Español</a></li>
            <li><a href="tw/index.php">中文(繁體)</a></li>
            <li><a href="cn/index.php">中文(简体)</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="nav"> 
            <li class="home"><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
            <li class="portfolio"><a href="portfolio.php">portfolio</a></li>
            <li class="about"><a href="about.php">about</a></li>
            <li class="contact"><a href="form.html">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#banner {
    background-color: #FBFBFB;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    width: 928px; /* 720 */
    border: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
}
#banner h1 {
    background: url(../images/logo.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
    display: inline; /* ie6 hack for double margin */
    height: 21px;
    font-size: 32px;
    float: left;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 169px;
}
#header a { 
    color: #999;
}
#lang {
    float: right;
}
#lang li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
}
#lang li a { 
    font-size: 10px;
}
#nav {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 0 0 20px;
}
#nav li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 30px 0 0;
}
#nav li a {
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav li a:hover {
    color: #666;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're using the firefox Web Developer Toolbar. If you use View Style Information to see exactly what style those list items have, what does it say? Anything about borders or padding to show why they're being positioned like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple fix would be to set the parent to position: relative and your menu to postion: absolute; bottom: 0; but it's not ideal.

I guess the best option is (since they have fixed heights), to give it a margin-top with the right amount of pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the height of your navigation div equal to the height of the logo image. Then use vertical-align: bottom to put the navigation at the bottom of its containing div.